# Rune binary representation prefix missing

Tags: go, unicode

I'm trying to understand runes in UTF-8/Go. I thought the rune was just suppose to be the bytes packed into a int32, however if I examine each byte of a UTF-8 code point, and the rune, the underlying binary representation doesn't match. More specifically the Unicode prefix for each byte is missing.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "中"
    r1 := []rune(s)[0]
    r2 := int32(r1)
    fmt.Printf("'%b %b %b'\n", s[0], s[1], s[2])
    fmt.Printf("'%b'\n", r1)
    fmt.Printf("'%b'\n", r2)
}
```

'11100100 10111000 10101101'
'100111000101101'
'100111000101101'

Is the rune not suppose to be the binary concatenation of the bytes. Where are the 1110, 10, 10 UTF-8 prefix for the three bytes in the rune representation?

Comment: A rune is a unicode code point, not UTF-8.

Comment: [The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings)

Answer (score -1):

tkausl answered in a comment

"A rune is a unicode code point, not UTF-8"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the thing:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "中"

    asRunes := []rune(s)
    fmt.Println(asRunes) // [20013]

    asBytes := []byte(s)
    fmt.Println(asBytes) // [228 184 173]
}
```

The character "中" is a unicode point. In the link given by @rocka2q "The Unicode standard uses the term “code point” to refer to **the item represented by a single value**."

"中" is a single value whose code point is `20013`.
Decomposing `20013` byte by byte is not the same as decomposing "中" byte by byte.